# Updating (or/and reading) different fields of a shared mutable object in different threads concurrently

Tags: java

Is Updating (or/and reading) different fields of a shared object in different threads concurrently, thread safe? And if it is, is it a good practice?

NOTE: ***Assuming we know that at any time no two (or more) threads will act (read or write) on the same field/property of this shared mutable object.***

E.G consider this code - is updating and reading the different fields of the shared mutable object `emp` in threads `t1`, `t2` and `t3` concurrently thread safe and an accepted practice?

```
package concurrency;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

public class SharedObjectApp {

  public static void main(String args[]){
      new App().doSomething();
  }

  public class App{

      Employee emp = new Employee(001, 100000, 32);

      public void doSomething(){

          Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
              @Override
              public void run(){
                  emp.setSalary(emp.getSalary() + 1000);
              }
          });

          Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  emp.setExp(emp.getExp() + 1);
              }
          });

          Thread t3 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i ++){
                      System.out.println(emp.getId());
                  }
              }
          });

          // is this thread safe?

          t1.start(); //updating salary
          t2.start(); //updating experience
          t3.start(); //getting id
      }
  }

  @NoArgsConstructor
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @Getter
  @Setter
  public static class Employee {
    int id;
    double salary;
    double exp;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not undefined behavior, but it can slow down your program. Writing and/or reading different fields at the same time (knowing they don't depend on each other) is quite safe to do so. Although this is a textbook example of a **false sharing** and shouldn't be done.

When accessing a memory location (class and it's members), that location gets copied into CPU cache-lines for faster access. If more threads try to access that memory location at the same time, it can invalidate these cache-lines to maintain memory coherency and thus slow down the execution.

[From oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewcy/index.html):

> However, simultaneous updates of individual elements in the same cache line coming from different processors invalidates entire cache lines, even though these updates are logically independent of each other. Each update of an individual element of a cache line marks the line as invalid. Other processors accessing a different element in the same line see the line marked as invalid. They are forced to fetch a more recent copy of the line from memory or elsewhere, even though the element accessed has not been modified. This is because cache coherency is maintained on a cache-line basis, and not for individual elements. As a result there will be an increase in interconnect traffic and overhead. Also, while the cache-line update is in progress, access to the elements in the line is inhibited.

[Jenkov has great resource on this](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/false-sharing.html)(They talk about multi-cpu systems, but it's still applicable as platform threads share the cache-lines).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this article.  However this ("cache-lines") talks about `OpenMP` API specifically?  Is this valid everywhere?

Comment: Yes, it's applicable everywhere. Jenkov has greate resource about this: https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java-concurrency/false-sharing.html
(it's applicable even on single cpu systems, since threads share cache-lines)